# On click fade out div then fade back in

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, settimeout

I've implemented a toggle views page, where you can toggle between a list and a grid the animations between toggle states is a bit ugly (toggle using the two links at the top to see what I mean): http://jsfiddle.net/qvLoLhy7/2/

To get around this issue I am trying to apply a `setTimeout` function on the toggle buttons so that I can fade out the parent div `#post-list` first, then perform the layout change and then finally fade `#post-list` back in again to show the updated layout. When I implement this though the fade in/out works but the layout doesn't change: http://jsfiddle.net/qvLoLhy7/

Can anybody help find out why this might be happening?

Here's a snippet of the JS:

```
function init() {
    optionSwitch.forEach( function( el, i ) {
        el.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) {

            $('#post-list').addClass('go'); // Fade out

            setTimeout(function() {
                _switch( this ); //Update layout. Switch refers to another function
            }, 500);


            setTimeout(function() {
                 $('#post-list').removeClass('go'); // Fade new layout back in
            }, 1000);

        }, false );
    } );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using jquery yet you are not really using jquery. Jquery comes with a fadeIn and fadeOut animation that you can use.

```
var $pl = $('#post-list');
$pl.fadeOut('slow', function(){
  //call back when animation is done
  //here you can apply layout changes
  $pl.fadeIn('slow', function(){
     //call back when the fade in animation is done
     //do other stuff here
  });
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/h3jxaj8n/) is a basic example.

You should also transform your code to the jquery equivalent.

Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: To a newb like myself, this doesn't make much sense to me, although I'm sure it does to an experienced pro!  I can't see how I can merge my code with yours to achieve the solution I need. Are you able to provide a bit more detail for me?